# preview/enlarge/zoom image api for my laravel app

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I am making my website and I want to show some images on it in small area, say in a `300x300` `<div>`.

**What I want is that the images can be previewed/enlarged when someone clicks on them, so that the user can have a better and bigger view of the image.**

**For ex**.- when you click a product image on **[flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com/hp-compaq-15-a002tu-laptop-3rd-gen-ci3-4gb-500gb-dos/p/itmdu4hksjdkjkd2?pid=COMDU4HKSJDKJKD2&srno=b_1&ref=8d056aa2-415e-4464-adf0-83fd9dd6f1df)** / **[jabong.com](http://www.jabong.com/rohit-bal-for-jabong-Hand-Block-Printed-Stitched-Detailed-Yoke-Anarkali-Co-Ordinated-Set-603768.html)**, you can see an enlarge view of the image. *In flipkart, it magnifies the image, and in jabong, you can rollover the image(which is kind of a zoom)*.

I have searched a lot over google for some kind of API for this but I couldn't find anything. So, **my question is - 'Is there an API which could do this kind of job? If not, then how is can this be implemented? Especially, what jabong does - rolling over the image'**.

**If there are no APIs,** please guide me on how this can be implemented. I don't want any code for implementation. **Just give me some good pointers to follow**.

Comment: Will http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ suffice?

Comment: @Roberto hmm, seems something related. taking a look. but its paid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

[Magnifier.js](http://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js/)

If this doesn't fit your needs.. a Google Search will reveal a few suggestions:

[jquery-zoom-effect-plugins](http://www.webdesignrazzi.com/2014/jquery-zoom-effect-plugins/)

Comment: magnifier.js will suffice and its under mit too.